# What's the point on using logarithms before differencing a time series in ARIMA?

Tags: logarithms, machine-learning, time-series, vector-auto-regression

I would like to know what's normally the point on ARIMA models, before differencing our time series in order to get stationarity, of applying a logarithm to our series. Does this helps our time series to be more stationary?
[How to build an ARIMA model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6HWT.png)

Comment: Try Stats.SE. This forum is more for general mathematics, your question is highly specialized